# How to cite a url in ieeetran bib file

Tags: bibliographies, citing, ieeetran, urls

I need to cite a wiki page. I cited like:

```
@MISC{wiki,
        author = {Wikipedia},
        title = {Pairing function {@MISC}},
        month = May,
        year = {2016},
        url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function/}
    }
```

But this error appears:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. .../en.wikipedia.org/wiki/function}}
```

Comment: To cite websites, I often used the misc class but instead of using the url field, I used the "Howpublished" field. Also make sure that you escape all LaTeX specific characters like the "_" in your wikipedia url with a \ in front of it. The real problem is probably the not-escaped _ - try escaping it like so: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing\_function/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just missed to call package `url`.  Then urls including `_` are set without problems.

See the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@MISC{wiki,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title  = {Pairing function {@MISC}},
  month  = May,
  year   = {2016},
  url    = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function/},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % <=========================================
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}

\title{This document}
\author{This author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2-6]
I have cited this document \cite{wiki}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

compiled without errors and only one warning (okay!), resulting from package `filecontents`, to have `bib` file and `tex` code together in one compilable MWE.